# How to retrieve tags inside certain tag for XML using GetElementsByTagName/SelectNode/SelectSingleNode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, webforms, xmldocument

Let say I have a XML with this format:

```
<TEST>
    <DRINK>
        <NAME>Ice tea</NAME>
        <NAME>Milo</NAME>
        <NAME>Coffee</NAME>
    </DRINK>
    <FOOD>
        <NAME>Fried Rice</NAME>
        <NAME>Hamburger</NAME>
        <NAME>Fried Noodles</NAME>
    </FOOD>
</TEST>
```

How to retrieve only food names and put them in the ASP.NET web form textbox?

This is my current code:

```cs
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filepath);
root = doc.DocumentElement;
TextBox1.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].InnerText;
TextBox2.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("NAME")[1].InnerText;
TextBox3.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("NAME")[2].InnerText;
```

This code will instead retrieve drink names instead of food names. How to make it read NAME tags in FOOD tag?

Comment: Are you sure your XML document is correct? It contains multiple root elements. Please provide a complete XML.

Comment: @YongShun i already change by adding <p>

Comment: Nope, see [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fUtawu). You will get multiple root element error.

Comment: @YongShun ok should be working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [`XmlNode.SelectNodes` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=net-6.0) with providing the XPath.

```cs
var foodElements = root.SelectNodes("FOOD/NAME");

Console.WriteLine(foodElement[0].InnerText);
Console.WriteLine(foodElement[1].InnerText);
Console.WriteLine(foodElement[2].InnerText);
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f8aa91)

Answer (score 0):

Basic xml parsing.

this:

```
    {
        string sXML
            =
          @"<TEST>
                <DRINK>
                    <NAME>Ice tea</NAME >   
                    <NAME>Milo</NAME >   
                    <NAME>Coffee</NAME> 
                </DRINK>   
                <FOOD>
                    <NAME>Fried Rice</NAME>      
                    <NAME>Hamburger</NAME>
                    <NAME>Fried Noodles</NAME>         
                </FOOD>
            </TEST>";


        XmlDocument myXml = new XmlDocument();
        myXml.LoadXml(sXML);

        XmlNodeList myNodes = myXml.SelectNodes("TEST/FOOD/NAME");

        foreach (XmlNode OneNode in myNodes)
        {
            Debug.Print(OneNode.InnerText);
        }
    }
```

output:
[image]